# [spark-cassandra-connector]How to convert scala implicit supported code to java in spark 2.3.1

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to refactor spark-cassandra used project from scala_2.11 to java_1.8.
I am using spark-sql_2.11-2..3.1 and spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.3.1.
Now i am trying to refactor code into java 1.8.

I have few implicits and DataFrame been used.

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import spark.implicits._
    &
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Now how to covert them into equivalent java code ? any sample ?

import of DataFrame is not recognized/defined , working fine with scala 2.11 now it is not working ...

What am I doing wrong here ? How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `DataFrame` in Java - it's always `DataSet` of class `Row`. In Scala, there is simple alias for that...

Here is the minimal example of Java code that reads data from Cassandra via `spark.sql`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class SparkTest1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("CassandraSpark")
    .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("select * from datastax.vehicle limit 1000");
    sqlDF.printSchema();
    sqlDF.show();
  }

}
```

or it could be done via `spark.read` ([full code](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/JoinTests.java#L36)):

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(ImmutableMap.of("table", "jtest", "keyspace", "test"))
        .load();
```

Comment: thank you  got it. one more thing in scala we have " _*  " operator

But in java equivalent ?

public static Dataset<Row> covertColumns(Dataset<Row> in_df ,  List<String> sequence  ) {
     //return  in_df.toDF(sequence: _*) // in scala we do like this 
     return  in_df.toDF(sequence ?????); //in java how to do ?
    }

Comment: it's done the same way as for other Java vararg function - they accept arrays, so you'll need to make `sequence.toArray(...)` to convert from `List` to `String[]`